# An error without actually explaining what's wrong

Tags: matlab

Ok, so I've defined the function MetBisectiei which has the following code:

```
function [xaprox] = MetBisectiei(Fun,a,b,eps)

Fa = Fun(a);
Fb = Fun(b);
if Fa*Fb>0
    xaprox = ('Error: The function has the same sign at points a and b.');
else
    N=ceil((log10(b-a)-log10(eps))/log10(2));
    for i = 1:n
        xaprox = (a+b)/2;
        Fxaprox=Fun(xaprox);
        if(Fxaprox == 0)
            break
        end

        if Fa*Fxaprox<0
            b=Fxaprox;
        else
            a=xaprox;
            Fa=Fxaprox;
        end
    end
end
```

And when I try to actually use the function to find the solution of an equation, I get the following error, which doesn't actually explain what's wrong:

```
Error in tema2_2 (line 8)
xaprox = MetBisectiei(f,0,1,eps);
```

The code to find the solution of the equation is this one:

```
syms x
f = x^3-7*x^2+14*x-6;
f = matlabFunction(f);
x = 0:4;
y = f(x);
plot(x,y);
eps = 10^(-5);
xaprox = MetBisectiei(f,0,1,eps);
```

Comment: Is that really the full error message? Strange! Did you try using the debugger to step through the code? Set a breakpoint by clicking on the left margin in the MATLAB Editor, then run your code. It will stop at the breakpoint and let you step through the code line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see few mistakes here. First you should terminate

```
function [xaprox] = MetBisectiei(Fun,a,b,eps)
```

with `end`, the one visible in your example just close `if` statement. The second problem is that `n` is not defined, probably you miss that matlab is case-sensitive, and `N` is not equal to `n`. So you should:

```
n=ceil((log10(b-a)-log10(eps))/log10(2));
```

If you fix this two things - your codes finish without any errors, (`xaprox = 0.5210`) tested on Matlab R2017b.

Comment: The first thing is actually not required, although highly recommended. `end` to end a function is implicitly added at the end of a file, *if that is the single thing in the file*. I.e. saving the above as `MetBisectiei.m` would work. The moment you do more in the script (class definitions, more functions, a script with a private function etc) the `end` is required

Comment: @Adriaan: Actually, you don’t even need `end` with private functions, only if you do the crazy nested scoping thing. The rule is either all functions in the file end with `end`, or none. A function in a script file does need an `end`.

Comment: There was no clear information about file structure, so I assume the function was not separated to script file.